# arch - /run/cryptsetup missing while formatting luks partition

Tags: linux, arch-linux, luks, cryptsetup

I'm relatively new to linux and I have just wiped my drive and I am installing arch linux from the start. When I run:

```
cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sda3
```

I get the following warning:

> WARNING: Locking directory /run/cryptsetup is missing!

It allows me to continue apparently but I decided to check if that would create me any problems in the future. So should I fix this now? What are the consequences of that situation? How can I fix it?

All threads I've seen seem to be about more serious problems which don't seem to be the case here (I'm guessing/hoping).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ignore the warning, `cryptsetup` will create the directory if it doesn't exist. There were some [discussions](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/18448) between systemd and cryptsetup who should be in charge of creating the directory. The warning was [changed](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/commit/1e7521c0564936fdbf098ce448e91e0ba25bffae) to a debug message with a different wording on cryptsetup 2.3.5 and newer.

The directory itself is used for header locking. From [cryptsetup manpage](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/cryptsetup.8.html#LUKS2_header_locking):

> The  LUKS2  on-disk metadata is updated in several steps and to achieve proper atomic update, there is a locking mechanism.  For
> an image in file, code uses flock(2) system call.  For a block device, lock is performed over a special file stored in a locking
> directory  (by  default  /run/lock/cryptsetup).  The locking directory should be created with the proper security context by the
> distribution during the boot-up phase.  Only LUKS2 uses locks, other formats do not use this mechanism.

(It says default is `/run/lock/cryptsetup` which is no longer true, default is now `/run/cryptsetup`, but that's just a documentation issue.)